# Overriding an operator overloading method

Tags: c#, class, operator-overloading, overriding

I have a class Parent and another class Child which inherits Parent.

I have an operator overloading method inside Parent and I would like to make it also work on Child. However I am not sure how to do this.

```
public class Parent
{
  public int age;
  public static Parent operator + (Parent a, Parent b)
  {
    Parent c = new Parent();
    c.age = a.age + b.age;
    return c;
  }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
   //other fields...
}
```

The only way I can think of is to copy the exact same method and logic to child. However I believe it's not a good way since the code is redundant: (especially when the code is very long)

```
public class Child : Parent
{
  public static Child operator + (Child a, Child b)
  {
    Child c = new Child();
    c.age = a.age + b.age;
    return c;
  }
}
```

I tried to do casting but it fails at runtime:

```
public class Child : Parent
{
  public static Child operator + (Child a, Child b)
  {
    return (Child)((Parent)a + (Parent)b);
  }
}
```

Is there a better method to achieve this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try using the type of parent to initiate a child class object like "Parent A = new Child();"

Comment: Even if I use Parent to initiate, how do I convert (Parent + Parent) back to Child?

Comment: Side note: when you face this problem it likely means no one will be able to understand what to expect from Parent + Child and hence will not be able to read the code. At this point going for builder methods or something different may be better option.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you have to create the `Child` object, but you could move the logic into a protected method.

```
public class Parent
{
  public int age;
  public static Parent operator + (Parent a, Parent b)
  {
    Parent c = new Parent();
    AddImplementation(a, b, c);
    return c;
  }

  protected static void AddImplementation(Parent a, Parent b, Parent sum)
  {
    sum.age = a.age + b.age;
  }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
  public static Child operator + (Child a, Child b)
  {
    Child c = new Child();
    AddImplementation(a, b, c);
    return c;
  }
}
```

Or another option would be to move the logic into protected constructors that the operator calls

```
public class Parent
{
    public int age;
    public static Parent operator +(Parent a, Parent b)
    {
        return new Parent(a, b);
    }

    protected Parent(Parent a, Parent b)
    {
      this.age = a.age + b.age;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public static Child operator +(Child a, Child b)
    {
        return new Child(a, b);
    }

    protected Child(Child a, Child b) : base(a,b)
    {
        // anything you need to do for adding children on top of the parent code.
    }
}
```